# Can I customize the positions in the heading of the public profile on careers?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I published [my public CV on Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fretje), and in the heading there is this line:

> Currently at Fretman IT Services and Solits VOF; 2 previous positions listed.

Is there a way to customize what is shown here? This has been changed since I added my last "experience". Previously, it was "Currently at ADP Belgium CVA", which is actually my current full time job. I would like that one to be up there again (as the other "experiences" are merely jobs "on the side"). Is this possible? Otherwise consider this a feature-request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found out that this line in the heading of your CV is dependent on what you filled out in the "time frame" portion of your different experiences. If you put something like "January 1998 - Current" in there, it will be listed in the heading of your public CV.

My adding of a new experience must have somehow cleared that portion of a previous experience though. I would file it as a bug, but I can't repeat it. Maybe it only happens once after migration from the previous version of Careers?